# Is it posible BLOCK windows APPS with a script?

Tags: python, windows

Is it possible to create a script to block certain windows apps in certain periods of time?

Something like that in android (when I click on the app, I'm not able of opening it):

[image]

Could that be done in windows? I would like to do it with python but if another language is the appropriate one, I don't mind.

I would be really helpful if someone could help me!
Also, if more info is needed, just tell and I will post it.

Comment: There's nothing "like that" or scriptable in Android. That's a core OS policy feature, not something done by script. You may be able to enable this policy through a Group policy, management APIs or even script calling the APIs, but that doesn't make them a script feature

Comment: Permissions like this are controlled in Windows through Group Policies, that can be applied by the OS itself to specific users, machines, groups of users or machines across an entire domain. In this case `“Don't run specified Windows applications“` can be used to block applications from starting. There may be a different setting for blocking apps on a schedule. You should probably ask at https://www.serverfault.com, the IT equivalent of  SO

Comment: What are you trying to do though? Blocking applications based on time is *not* something  typically done in a corporate or educational environment. Typically there are allowed logon/logoff hours and Windows enforces this through the `Force logoff when logon hours expire` setting and more. What you ask is more relevant for phones and tablets, in which case you'll find it in the Family management features of App Store apps. There may be similar features n managed devices like corporate laptops

Comment: @PangotisKanavos the purpose of the script would be to block certain apps like games or social media while working to be more productive

Comment: Post at serverfault.com then. This isn't a programming question at all. You can use a script to enable those features, typically through Powershell, but the feature itself is part of Windows. Companies have been blocking apps like that for 20 years

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm going to ask there.